# Mamp Apache problems - El Capitan Upgrade

Tags: mamp, osx-elcapitan, mamp-pro

I was running MAMP PRO 2.2 on Mavericks without a problem.

BUT THEN I upgraded  OS to El Capitan

Now when I connect to MAMP I get this message

> Start Apache failed Apache wasn't able to start. Please check log for
>   more information.

I tried  trouble testing Apache by running apachectl configtest

and got the below

> httpd: Syntax error on line 58 of /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf:
>   Cannot load libexec/apache2/mod_authn_default.so into server:
>   dlopen(/usr/libexec/apache2/mod_authn_default.so, 10): image not found

Can anyone help with this problem

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your MAMP PRO is outdated. Upgrade to MAMP PRO 3.5, runs fine in 10.11.

Peter